# Can I use BouncyCastle's Tweakable Block Ciphers using the standard Java Cipher API?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

BouncyCastle provides an implementation of Threefish, which can take a tweak as a parameter:

```
ThreeFishEngine engine = new ThreeFishEngine(256);
engine.init(true, new TweakableBlockCipherParams(...));
```

However, `TweakableBlockCipherParams` is not compatible with the `AlgorithmParameter` type that is used by instances of Java's default `Cipher`.

Is there a way to initialize this cipher with a tweak?

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Threefish-256/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use Bouncy Castle's *Threefish* algorithm through Java's cryptography API if you don't want to use a *tweak* parameter during ciphering. Through Java's API you can only introduce a *key* and an *initialization vector* parameter, but this won't be used as a tweak parameter (I explained why after the code example, see below).

Also, for the below example to work you have to update your JRE/JDK with the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files which you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). There are different versions for Java 7 and 8.

If you don't want to use a tweak parameter you can use the Threefish algorithm through the standard crypto API like this.

```
static final BouncyCastleProvider PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Threefish-1024", PROVIDER);
    kg.init(1024);
    SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();

    byte[] plaintext = "Hi! I'm cat!".getBytes();
    byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(key, plaintext);
    System.out.println(new String(decrypt(key, ciphertext)));
    // prints "Hi! I'm cat!"
}

static byte[] encrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] plaintext) throws Exception {
    return encryptOrDecrypt(true, key, plaintext);
}

static byte[] decrypt(SecretKey key, byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
    return encryptOrDecrypt(false, key, ciphertext);
}

static byte[] encryptOrDecrypt(boolean encrypt, SecretKey key, byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Threefish-1024/CBC/PKCS5Padding", PROVIDER);
    // note that we are creating a dummy iv parameter, in this case it
    // should be 128 bytes long, because if it's not an exception is raised
    cipher.init(encrypt ? Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE : Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[128]));
    return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
}
```

I've downloaded a Bouncy Castle JAR with debug symbols [from here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and debugged the above code. The call to `Cipher.init` lands in [`Threefish.init`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/ThreefishEngine.java#L158) and the variable `params` will be an instance of `KeyParameter` and not `TweakableBlockCipherParameters` in our case. So, `tweakBytes` will be null and won't be used during ciphering.

Knowing this, *right now* it's impossible to use the Java API to supply the tweak parameter to the underlying Threefish cipher engine.

<sub>[Link to another very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30513529/433835)</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that a tweak is the same thing as an IV?  I was looking through the source code, trying to figure out if they ended up in the same place, and it didn't seem to me that they did.

Comment: Also, when I run this, I get an `InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`.

Comment: @codebreaker You're right about the IV thing. About that and the `Illegal key size` exception please see my updated my answer.